# jQuery $(window).resize not firing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

For environmental reasons, I am only able to test this in Firefox currently, so I don't know what's happening in other browsers. I am trying to track down why binding the window resize event isn't working.

This is a legacy project with a lot of JavaScript, and I cannot find anywhere where events are being unbound, or any other bindings to resize.

jQuery version is 1.7.3

I have code that looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
       console.log("resize 1");
    });
    $(window).on("resize", function(){
       console.log("resize 2");
    });
    window.onresize = function(){
     console.log("resize 3");
    }
});
```

When I resize the window, only "resize 3" is logged.

If I do:

```
$(window).trigger("resize");
```

Then all three are logged to the console.

If I remove window.onresize - nothing happens when I resize, but triggering resize logs.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 24.

Comment: I'm seeing this in FF, too, with code that works in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I'd make sure, that this function is really loaded with the document ready event and use only the .resize function from jquery. It works on every platform as far as I know. So the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    console.log("this really works for me");
  });
});
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/nTej2/

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it with document ready as well. Something is blocking jQuery where the native call to window.onresize works fine.